# Problems with Rspec and/or Rspec-core

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec

I installed rspec and also did rspec --init. (I've gone through directions from here http://rspec.codeschool.com/levels/1 multiple times).

However, every time I try to run a spec from my command line, it won't load (please see below). Please help if you know what may be going wrong.

> /Library/Ruby/Site/2.0.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require': cannot load such file -- zombie (LoadError)
>       from /Library/Ruby/Site/2.0.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in`require'
>       from /Users/Qureshi/spec/lib/zombie_spec.rb:2:in `<top (required)>'
>       from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/rspec-core-3.2.0/lib/rspec/core/configuration.rb:1226:in`load'
>       from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/rspec-core-3.2.0/lib/rspec/core/configuration.rb:1226:in `block in load_spec_files'
>       from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/rspec-core-3.2.0/lib/rspec/core/configuration.rb:1224:in`each'
>       from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/rspec-core-3.2.0/lib/rspec/core/configuration.rb:1224:in `load_spec_files'
>       from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/rspec-core-3.2.0/lib/rspec/core/runner.rb:97:in`setup'
>       from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/rspec-core-3.2.0/lib/rspec/core/runner.rb:85:in `run'
>       from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/rspec-core-3.2.0/lib/rspec/core/runner.rb:70:in`run'
>       from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/rspec-core-3.2.0/lib/rspec/core/runner.rb:38:in `invoke'
>       from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/rspec-core-3.2.0/exe/rspec:4:in`'
>       from /usr/bin/rspec:23:in `load'
>       from /usr/bin/rspec:23:in`'

Comment: What command are you using to run, and what folder are your rspec files?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try putting the following at the top of your spec_helper.rb:

`require_relative '../lib/zombie'`

Answer (score 1):

Be sure your terminal's current folder is Users/Qureshi then run the command `rspec spec`

If it does not work, your file (or entire folder) is access blocked, or does not exist in /Users/Qureshi/spec/lib/

Comment: Thanks! For some reason (or maybe that's how it is), the rspec folder wasn't created in the same folder with the spec_helper file so I had to put those in the same folder and THEN run my command from the right folder! It finally worked.